# Swift: How to use library: Alamofire-SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm having trouble trying to get this library Alamofire-SwiftyJSON (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON) to work.

I created a new project and downloaded the Alamofire-SwiftyJSON library and dragged everything into my project navigation area.

However when I go into the ViewController and add:

```
import AlamofireSwiftyJSON
```

I get the error: **no such module import AlamofireSwiftyJSON**

Can someone tell me how to add this project manually. Ideally step by step so that I can get this code to work:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
     .responseSwiftyJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
                 println(json)
                 println(error)
               }
```

Thank you

Comment: yes but I got the error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ';'

Comment: just try removing the import statement. Does it work ? Swift doesn't need import statements to includeother swift files

Comment: Nope on the line: Alamofire.request it says use of unresolved identifier 'Alamofire'

Comment: When you added the swift file to your project in Xcode, did you check your application in the targets ? If not you can start again by deleting the files and adding them again

Comment: Do you mean the dialogue that pops up asking where to save them and copy if needed? Yes It was correct and I clicked yes to copy items if needed

Comment: In your project go to your project target >> "Build Phases" under "Target Dependencies" press  +  and add the frameworks

Comment: now i'm getting: Cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'

Comment: argh! I thought that including libraries was supposed to make this easier!

Comment: If there's any mention of  XCTest , you're loading or linking against the testing target somehow.
Consider importing both Alamofire and SwiftJSON independently following their readme for installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your Deployment Target? is it **< 8.0** ? if so those targets that do not support embedded frameworks and as such all you need to do is:

- Drag Alamo.Swift to your project Navigation (Make sure you copy files if needed)
- Remove instances of 'Usage' **Alamofire.request** will become **request**

so the code you have will be:

```
request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
 .responseSwiftyJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
             println(json)
             println(error)
           }
```

So now, that is that framework. Since I have some time now I will show you how to get it all working and neaten it up a little.

Once you have done the above, do this:

- drag SwiftyJSON.swift to your project navigation area

Again... Make sure you copy files if needed. That is it for the framework also.

Right to neaten it up a little - You don't have to do this but its always better to use variables and arrays where possible to make cleaner and speed up coding time. For your example above do this:

```
var url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
var arr_parameters = [
    "foo": "bar"
]

request(.GET, url, parameters: arr_parameters)
```

Its also a good idea to incorporate some error testing so that you can debug things easier and also provide fallbacks etc...

so, with this in mind, your entire code should look like:

```
var url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
var arr_parameters = [
    "foo": "bar"
]

request(.GET, url, parameters: arr_parameters)
   .responseJSON { (req, res, json, error) in
            if(error != nil) {
                NSLog("Error: \(error)")
                println(req)
                println(res)
            }
            else {
                NSLog("Success: \(url)")
                var json = JSON(json!)
            }
    }
```

There was a really good article covering this in [SwiftMonthly](http://swiftmonthly.com/?utm_source=StackOverflow&utm_medium=StackOverflow&utm_campaign=StackOverflow)

I hope this helps. Good luck and keep us posted.

Answer (score 2):

First follow your link to the Alamofire-SwiftyJSON project. There download the zip for the full project.
Also follow the link for the Alamofire project and download the fullzip, same thing again for the swiftyJSON project.

Now here is what you need to do :

1. Add the file Alamofire-SwiftyJSON.swift that you can find in the 'source' folder of the Alamofire-SwiftyJSON zip that you previously download and add it to your project. Leave the checkbox for 'copy if needed' and for your target as is.
2. On Xcode, add file through file > 'Add files to "MyProject" and select the file 'Alamofire.xcodeproj' from the Alamofire zip that you downloaded. Here are the options:

[image: Options for the adding of the alamo project]

You can check the 'copy files if needed' if you want. If you don't, be sure to keep the folder for the alamofire project.
3. Do the exact same thing for the swiftyJSON project. By adding the 'SwiftyJSON.xcodeproj' file.
4. Go to your project settings > Build Phase > Link Binary With Libraries
5. Add the Alamofire and SwiftyJSON frameworks (choose the right frameworks depending on if you are developing for iphone or mac os x) like that :

[image: Add Alamofire and SwiftyJSON frameworks]

6. Go to whatever part of the program you need your request to be made (e.g. ViewController or AppDelegate) and add the following code below the initial import statement

   import Alamofire
7. Add your request with the following code:

   Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
               .responseSwiftyJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
                   println(json)
                   println(error)
           }
8. Have fun coding !

Comment: Sorry but this isn't working either. I started a fresh project and added just those three files to the project navigation area. When I build the project I get error: No such module 'Alamofire'

Comment: sorry to be a pain haha

Comment: Not a problem, I can try in a few hours when I get home but until then I have not access to Xcode. i'll edit my answer then

Comment: Didn't check but it looks like I was too late

Comment: Haha sorry pal, that above solution did work. Any thoughts on this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304731/swift-pass-multiple-values-between-views (noob alert)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cocoapods now. Pod install Alamofire and SwiftyJSON separately and just bring in AlamofireSwiftyJSON.swift into your xcode project folder.

Then in the view controller or whatever you want to use it, import Alamofire and SwiftyJSON at the top of your file.

Then below code snippet should compile fine.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
                     println(json)
                     println(error)
                  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved by reading at [Cocoapods.org](http://cocoapods.org) Get Started paragraph:

[image]

1) Close xCode application (important!)

2) from the Terminal, inside your project folder type:

```
open YourApp.xcworkspace
```

Now everything will work :)