# Swift: Pass multiple values between views

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, parameters

I have a view that has two text fields and a button.

```
@IBOutlet var inputURL: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var inputName: UITextField!

@IBAction func submitUrlButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

and a second view that has two variables:

```
var submittedURL = ""
var submittedName = ""

println("Name \(submittedName)")
println("URL \(submittedURL)")
```

In Swift How do I pass the values entered in the two text fields and assign them to those variables in the second view?

Thanks

EDIT FOR THETOM:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var inputURL: UITextField!

@IBAction func submitBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("submissionSegue", sender: self)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of the next view controller
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as BrandsViewController
    destinationVC.submittedURL.text = inputURL.text
}
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about the following points:
- are those views or view controllers ?
- who is creating those views or viewControllers ?
- is there a link between the two view ?

Comment: @TheTom Yes they are viewcontrollers and they have a segue called 'submissionSegue'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method prepareForSegue.

In the first view (the one from which the segue is coming from) write the following code :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of the next view controller 
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as CustomViewController
    destinationVC.submittedURL = inputURL.text
    destinationVC.submittedName = inputName.text
}
```

Here CustomViewController is the custom class of the UIViewController to which the segue is going to.

To perform the segue programmatically in your button @IBAction do that :

```
@IBAction func buttonWasClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("submissionSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Then how do I get the button to initiate the segue change?

Comment: also, When I add that code into the viewcontroller I get: Use of undeclared type 'UIViewController'

Comment: to perform the segue add this to the IBAction : performSegueWithIdentifier("submissionSegue", sender: self)

Comment: Check if UIViewController is spelled correctly. I previously made a typo. Else import UIKit at the beginning of your file

Comment: @TheTom UIViewController does not have member submittedURL or submittedName therefore it should be cast as an object that extend UIViewController

Comment: Replace UIViewController by the name of the custom class you are using

Comment: @TheTom Thanks, I have done that and it loaded fine. However when I type anything into the textfield and press the button the app crashes. I get this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Comment: Can you update your post with the full code ? It's hard to see where that optional is

Comment: @TheTom sure - Give me a moment - I'll add it to the answer

Comment: @TheTom added to the main answer for you.

Comment: Can you tell us on which line the exception gets thrown ? For the optional I mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70161/discussion-between-the-tom-and-danniecoderboi).

Answer (score 1):

Since your view controllers are linked with segue you can override the prepareForSegue method in first view controller and pass data by doing so

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "secondViewController") { // here secondViewController is your segue identifier            
        var secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController // where SecondViewController is the name of your second view controller class
        secondViewController.submittedURL = inputURL.text
        secondViewController.submittedName = inputName.text
    }
}
```

And to performSegue inside your button action use perfromSegueWithIdentifier method

```
@IBAction func submitUrlButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    //replace identifier with your identifier from storyboard
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The simplest way of accessing values globally not neccessary to pass with segue
```

> **First View controller**

```
import UIKit
var submittedURL:NSString? // declare them here
var submittedName:NSString? // Now these two variables are accessible globally 
class YourViewController : UIViewController 
{
@IBOutlet var inputURL: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var inputName: UITextField!

@IBAction func submitUrlButton(sender: AnyObject) {
 if inputURL.text == "" && inputName.text == ""
{ 
 //Show an alert here etc
}
else {
 self.submittedURL.text = inputURL.text
self.submittedName.text = inputName.text
 }
}
}
```

> **SecondView Controller**

```
import UIKit
class SecondviewController: UIViewController 
{
//inside viewDidload
println(submittedURL)
println(submittedName)
}
```